# Problem with LightDm on Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: login, startup, lightdm, session

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 server and installed lightDM (apt-get install lightdm) , started lightdm (start lightdm) a login screen appears with an error "Failed to start session" as response to login. all commands as root. Any idea?

Comment: Is X server running when you start LightDM? Since LightDM is used for graphical logins, it seems to me that the display server needs to be running for it to work. (Why are you trying to run LightDM on a server, if I may ask? Servers are normally used to not have a graphical interface.)

Comment: Did you install any desktop environment (AFAIK lightdm doesn't so so by default)? What are the contents of the /usr/share/xsessions/ directory?

Comment: don't know how to install or start X server , or even wthat is X server, this machine is going to be used also as workstation for billing on a bookstore. I have none linux experience.

Comment: the directory xsessions doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

On ubuntu-server if you want to also use it as a desktop you will have to install a desktop environment. Run the following commands to install ubuntu desktop:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Now you will be able to start the graphical desktop with existing username and password.

Comment: done!  if you could help me a bit more, now I have session started with the graphical ubuntu desktop, I just need to open terminal in windows with XMING.

Comment: when tried to use XMING the terminal connects to server, a window opens in my PC with Windows but a gray screen with a mouse cursor is the only I get. No login options.  What else should I install or configure on the server?